# Does videojs support dynamic/adaptive rtmp streaming?

Tags: streaming, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront, video.js

I was going through the videojs player to implement the amazon cloudfront with dynamic bit rate switching, but could not find any supporting doc. So  could anyone please guide us on how to implement cloudfront on videojs player with dynamic bitrate switching.

thanks